# Multilanguage Django website with custom URLs

Tags: django, internationalization, multilingual

I'm stuck a little and need your advices guys... I'm creating the website which will be translated in two languages. For example I have two urls /gallery/pictures and /galerija/paveikslai (these are the same but different languages) which points to the same content (for example will show gallery of paintings).

Of course depending on the link it should change the language of the content and the page itself. Any ideas how to do it better? Maybe I need to use the language prefix? If yes, how then I will deal with it (middleware or something)?

Maybe someone already did the same and has some nice advices or code to show?

Thanks,
Ignas

Comment: Have you looked at `django Internationalization and localization`? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

Comment: sure. But you don't telling me to have all the content which gets from DB get translated like this? When you have dynamic content and it goes from DB, I prefer to save this different content in db with the language indicator. And then by using different link or slug, you getting different content. To translate some words, sentences - it's fine to have translations files, sure.

Comment: This is rather old blog post but can be helpful nonetheless: http://www.muhuk.com/2010/01/dynamic-translation-apps-for-django/

Comment: thanks! No more advices? Strange :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

settings.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

GALLERY_URL = _('gallery')
PICTURES_URL = _('pictures')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^'+settings.GALLERY_URL+'/'+settings.PICTURES_URL+'/$',
    'my_view',         
    name='my_view'),
```

You should somehow validate that GALLERY_URL and PICTURES_URL are not empty.

Comment: Nice tip. I did it by separating url.py files depended on language. I also put language prefix. Middleware check the language in url. This helps to have more user friendly link. But your tip is also nice. Thanks.